# Need Similar option in Alamofire to setRequestProperty as in HttpURLConnection Android

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am struggling a lot to set Authorisation token as a connection request property in Alamofire Swift.

I tried sending Auth token in headers and was able to achieve that.

In android we set auth token as `HttpUrlConnection`.`setRequestProperty` and the APIs are working fine, but in Swift I have to use same APIs but sending auth token in headers is not helping out.

Options I tried:-

1. Creating `MutableURlRequest` and setting `HTTPAdditionalHeaders`.
2. var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
           let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
           configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

Please anyone help me sending auth token as a request property rather than a header.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could send authorization token along with other request's parameters, something like this:

```
private var parameters: [String: AnyObject]? {
    switch self {
        case Profile(let token, ...):
            return ["authCode" : token, ...]
        ...
    }
}
```

However it's recommended to be send as header, so just for heads-up, this is how I do it:

```
import Alamofire

// Helper to build Alamofire Requests

enum APIRouter {

    static let baseURL = "http://..."

    case Authorize(token: String)
    ...

}

extension APIRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
        URLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        // Server token is set after authorisation and will be applied to the following requests 
        if let token = SecureManager.sharedInstance.serverToken {
            URLRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }

        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
        let request = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        return request
    }

    private var URL: NSURL {
        let baseURL = NSURL(string: APIRouter.baseURL)
        return baseURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path)
    }

    private var path: String {
        switch self {
        case Authorize:
            return "rest/oauth/authorize"
        ...
        }
    }

    private var method: Alamofire.Method {
        switch self {
        case Authorize:
            return .POST
        ...
        }
    }

    private var parameters: [String: AnyObject]? {
        switch self {
        ...
        }
    }

}
```